# how to display two model in cgridview (yii framework)?

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am new to yii framework. I have 2 model (`Tables` has many `PeriodeDatas`) and want to display data from model `PeriodeDatas` in `CGridView` on tables index view, but cant get this to work.

**Tables** columns

```
The followings are the available columns in table 'nkr_tables':
@property integer $id
@property string $title
@property string $periode
```

**Tables** model relation

```
'periodeData' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PeriodeDatas', 'table_id')
```

**PeriodeDatas** columns

```
The followings are the available columns in table 'nkr_periode_datas':
@property integer $id
@property integer $table_id
@property string $year
```

**PeriodeDatas** model relation

```
'table' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tables', 'table_id')
```

**Tables** controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Tables('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();

    if (isset($_GET['Tables']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Tables'];

    $this->render('index', array('model' => $model));
}
```

**Tables View**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
array(
    'id'=>'tables-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'header' => 'Data Title'
            ),
        'periode',
        array(
            'name' => 'periodeData.year',
            'header' => 'Tahun'
            )
        ),
    'selectionChanged'=>'function(id) { location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('tables/view').'/"+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}'
    )
);
```

**Result:** http://prntscr.com/18jpp1

How to display `year` from model `PeriodeDatas` in `CGridView` on tables view?

**sorry for bad english*

---

**Update** :
I tried adding `'value' => '$data->periodeData->year'` but get an error `Trying to get property of non-object`

**Update** :
I tried `'value' => '$data->periodeData[0]->year'` and it display the year correctly, but if there are only 1 record on the table. When there is more than 1 record on the table, it produces an error `Undefined offset: 0`

Then i tried `'value' => '$data->periodeData[$data->id]->year'` and give me error `Undefined index: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that create the model of periodedatas and use the relation of **table** in the view to access the records

Because u are accessing the array() not a string as it is HAS_MANY Relation

U may read this thread [Search by a HAS_MANY relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/428/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation/)

Comment: i got an error `Trying to get property of non-object` for accessing `$model->periodeData->year` in foreach

Comment: just Var_dump($model->periodeData) see wheather it is an array or object . if u are getting that error means $model->periodeData is an array() not an object

Comment: `print_r($model->periodeData)` return an empty array. it should be `2013`

Comment: $model->periodeData will return an array of PeriodeDatas objects if any exist, otherwise it will return an empty array.

Comment: @Ninad You might want that loop to look like `foreach($model->periodeData as $periodData) $periodDataYear[] = $periodData->year;` since as it is, each loop will replace the array with the next PeriodeDatas object.

Comment: I thought $model->periodeData will return an array of object so i had suggested that solution but @maswahyu is saying it will return an empty array .And in tables model relation periodeData is related with HAS_MANY relationship